# Переопределение скрытия блока при скролле

Tags: javascript, jquery, прокрутка

Есть блок который нужно скрывать при скролле вниз, но также надо чтобы по клике на кнопку его можно было показать, затем при скролле вниз он опять скрывается. Я написал следующее:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        // ===webazex start
        function toggleHeader() {
            if ($(this).scrollTop() > 10) {
                $('.mobile__content-bottom').hide(300);
            } else {
                $('.mobile__content-bottom').show(300);
            }
        }
        $(window).on('load resize scroll',toggleHeader);
        $('.box__toogle-menu-container').click(function () {
            $('.mobile__content-bottom').show(300);
        });
```

А вот так я пробовал сделать скрытие блока конткретно при событии скролла а не при скролле на столько-то пикселей:

```
 function toggleHeader() {
            if ($(this).scrollTop() < 10) {
                $('.mobile__content-bottom').show(300);
            } else {
                $('.mobile__content-bottom').hide(300);
            }
        }
```

Срабатывание обеих вариантов настроено на эти события

```
$(window).on('load resize scroll',toggleHeader);
```

Появление сделано так:

```
$('.box__toogle-menu-container').click(function () {
            $('.mobile__content-bottom').show(300);
        });
```

По факту при клике на кнопку показать - он показывается и сразу скрывается, так как срабатывает условие в функции. Как мне можно переопределять это условие и показывать блок, или же сделать так чтобы блок скрывался не при скролле на столько то элементов а просто при скролле, так даже правильнее будет.

Comment: `$(document).ready(function() { $(window).on('load', ...); });` не гарантирует перехват события `load`. `JQuery.ready` не является полным эквивалентом события `DOMContentLoaded`. `$(window).on('load', ...);` следует выносить из тела `JQuery.ready`, чтобы гарантированно перехватить событие `load`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем проблема оказалась проста как гусь. При скролле блок скрывался, а при появлении инициировал скролл на пару пикселей попричине position: relative;, из за чего опять срабатывал скрипт его скрывающий, и так он циклился. По факту нужно было дать блоку position: absolute;

Answer (score 1):

Нужно использовать два дополнительных "перекрывающих друг-друга" css класcа. При нажатии на кнопку "динамически" создавать еще один обработчик на `resize/scroll`, но который выполняется единожды (заметьте, используется `one` вместо `on`).

```js
$(function() {

  function onScroll() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 10) {
      $('.fx').addClass('inactive');
    } else {
      $('.fx').removeClass('inactive');
    }
  }

  function onClick() {
    $('.fx').addClass('active');
    $(window).one('resize scroll', function() {
      $('.fx').removeClass('active');
    });
  }

  $(window).on('resize scroll', onScroll);
  $('.btn').on('click', onClick);

  onScroll();
        
});
```

```css
.fx {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0; right: 0; left: 0;
  background-color: yellow;
  transition: visibility ease 300ms, opacity ease 300ms;
  padding: 10px;
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}
.fx.inactive {
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
}
.fx.active {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="fx">HEADER</div>

<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>

<button class="btn">Click me</button>

<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>

<button class="btn">Click me</button>

<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
```